# Java balance the load into many JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, io, jvm

My java application does much IO operations and consumes much memory and CPU (serializations and deserializations). Generally some time my application throws out of memory exceptions in certain times even though heap sizes have already been increased and GC pauce time reduced..:(  Therefore, the expected performance level cannot be gained. I found some questions [like thiis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411265/splitting-workload-into-two-seperate-jvms-on-same-machine-performance-question)  . But they are theoritical and couldn't find which suits my problem.

Currently I am share the load among threads. How ever I am looking whether any performance improvement can be gained by putting the load into the different JVM. I want to know

- Can we share the application tasks among different JVMs? if can,How ?(any example?) will there be a performance improvement ?

Comment: Yes, you can. It will not be easy, and it probably won't give you a performance improvement over threads. (in fact it will probably make things slower)

Comment: You May want to look into Hadoop.

Comment: You can use multiple machines.  If your JVM is using all the resources of a machine, using more JVMs will only help if you use more machines.  Note: if you improve the CPU and memory usage you can improve the performance by a factor of 10x or more.  I would make sure your application is optimised before attempting to scale it horizontally,

Comment: @PeterLawreyj > Thanks for your comment. Little not clear. "If your JVM is using all the resources of a machine, using more JVMs will only help if you use more machines. Note: if you improve the CPU and memory usage"   .?  you menat that if the existing jvm consumes all the resources, more JVMs improves the peformance ? if it is so, any resources or links please ?

Comment: If possible you can think of Externalization instead of Serialization if you feel that consumes more time

Comment: What Peter is saying is that if your machine had 16gb RAM available and the JVM uses all of it, you won't get anywhere by adding more processes into the mix. Scale horizontally by adding more machines, optimize the program or add more hardware to the single machine.

Answer (score 3):

> My java application does much IO operations and consumes much memory
>   and CPU (serializations and deserializations).

Are you referring to Disk I/O or Network I/O or both?
If the bottleneck is disk I/O and you have a single SATA hard disk, then more threads or jvm on the same host will not help. Load balancing across hosts or other disk options can help. You need to try it out.

> some time my application throws out of memory exceptions

This could be due to multiple reasons. If its the heap and if you see there is no memory leak or unwanted memory utilization then increasing heap might help. This could affect gc pause times. This depends on how much heap you already have and the gc options in place. Multiple jvms might help.
Creating large number of threads can also cause OOM.

If you are CPU bound then increasing threads count or having multiple jvms will not help unless the number of CPUs are increased.

Sharing across multiple jvms means running multiple instances of your application. This can be achieved via load balancer. [Edit] Different jvms can talk to each other via RMI etc, but i suppose you are not really looking at inter process communication.

First step is to identify the bottlenecks via profiling and load tests and then start tuning it.